# Ajax call behaving sychronously

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have an application that firstly makes an ajax call for a heavy and long operation (that uses a lot of the DB), and it also makes other ajax calls for a light and fast operation which only checks the progress of the big operation.

The problem is that the ajax call for the short operation does not get a response while the big operation doesn't get its response as well. Which is weird because they are expected to run simultaneously.

When I manually check (on phpmyadmin) the progress of the big operation, the (MySQL) DB responds ok. So the problem might not be table lock issue, but i'm unsure.

Does anyone have an idea to help me?

Comment: Two pages using the same session can not be requested at the same time, as PHP queues the request to avoid concurrent writes.

Comment: @adeneo Actually you can but you have to tell PHP: Call `session_write_close()` before beginning the heavy load operation. Obviously, you can't write to the session after that anymore.

Comment: @hanzi - Then the session is closed, and if it's not the same session, you can request as many pages as you'd like, how else would a webserver be able to serve the same page to many users at the same time.

Comment: @adeneo The session will be only closed within the script that calls `session_write_close()`. Subsequent requests can still use it. It just makes PHP remove the session lock by promising it that you won't do any more writes.

Comment: @hanzi - yes, it ends the session, but it doesn't delete the session variables.

Comment: @adeneo I think the word "end" is misleading in this context. The only difference is that you cannot make changes to session variables in the currently running script after calling this function. So the session lives on just as well and did NOT end.

Comment: @adeneo, your solution solved my problem. thanks so much. if you want, answer the question properly so I can accept it and the answer. I don't know if using session_write_close() will have further impacts on my application, so I'll do more testing. But it worked for now.

Comment: @hanzi - it's called session_write_ **close**, and in [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) the first line says "Write session data and ***end session***", so I would think it was pretty clear that it ends the session ?

Comment: I don't think the session is closed after calling that function, since the user is still logged into the system.

Comment: Ending the session and deleting `$_SESSION` is not the same thing, that's why you in some cases can end and start sessions without loosing the data.

Comment: @adaneo That's why I said it's misleading. An alias for that function is `session_commit()` which is more clear, I guess. Feel free to try if yourself: `<?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['foo']++; session_write_close(); ?>`

Comment: @hanzi - I don't have to try it, I've used session_write_close a lot myself, it's especially useful when building stuff that uses things like cURL, and using one ajax call to do the cURL call, and then post the progress back to a file and using another ajax call to get the progress, but that requires the closing of the session in the first ajax call to open up for the second ajax call. These days I just use websockets instead, much simpler, but a few years ago I used this all the time, and that's why I know you can't access the same session twice at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call session_write_close() before beginning the heavy load operation. Obviously, you can't write to the session after that anymore. Two pages using the same session can not be requested at the same time, as PHP queues the request to avoid concurrent writes.

Calling session_write_close() will cause the server to be able to respond to a client request before the previous request has been responded (if any).